# Pylint Error: Attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylint

Here in VSCode whenever I write the following line `from . import dispatcher` pylint always gives error statement saying Attempted relative import beyond top-level package.

But when I run the module using this command: `python -m src.train` the program runs without flashing any error. Here is the screenshot from the VSCode editor:

[image]

Does someone know who to solve this thing in VSCode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add an empty `__init__.py` file of the folder that contains your `dispatcher.py` file, then all the `.py` files under the folder, as whole, should be recognized as a package. And the lint error should dismiss.

Comment: Strange that this error doesnt occur if I use PyCharm IDE

Comment: @anoop4real It is actually pylint related. I am not familiar with PyCharm IDE, but if there is like a plugin/extension that enables inline hint that getting output from pylint, you should also came in across the same error.